# How to access items sold from Square POS Transactions?

Tags: square-connect, square

I am trying to build a reporting script that GETs the sales from a particular period in our retail location and is able to access the "line items sold" data of each transaction.

Unfortunately, it looks like the "transaction" object does not have any line items associate with it nor does it contain an associated order id.

How can I view each transaction and its corresponding line items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SearchOrders](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/orders-api/search-orders) to query for orders which have itemized items in the each order.